# Fitting a joint log-normal distribution when observations include zeros

Tags: fitting, lognormal-distribution

I have a set of realizations of two random variables, $X_1$ and $X_2$, and I am trying to estimate the parameters of their joint distribution.

I assume that the joint distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is multivariate log-normal. That is, the joint distribution of the variables $Y_i = \log X_i$ is a multivariate normal distribution.

However, the process that generated $X_2$ caused certain values to clip to zero, as can be seen in the following realizations:

| $x_1$ | $x_2$ |
| --- | --- |
| 0.00296175 | 4.37481e-6 |
| 0.0211956 | 3.13081e-5 |
| 0.0241599 | 3.56867e-5 |
| 0.00688606 | 1.01714e-5 |
| 0.00337927 | 4.99154e-6 |
| 0.00188527 | 2.78474e-6 |
| 0.433801 | 0.00064077 |
| 2.90093 | 0.00428497 |
| 0.00450206 | 6.65001e-6 |
| 9.40782 | 0.0138963 |
| 0.00150354 | 2.22088e-6 |
| 0.0998467 | 0. |
| 4.26844 | 0.00630493 |
| ⋮ |  |
| 0.00419922 | 6.20269e-6 |
| 0.0983797 | 0.000145317 |
| 0.0923995 | 0. |
| 0.135952 | 0.000200815 |
| 0.00662665 | 9.78825e-6 |
| 0.028367 | 4.19011e-5 |
| 0.00179699 | 2.65434e-6 |
| 0.0073301 | 1.08273e-5 |
| 15.4355 | 0.0227998 |
| 0.00160651 | 2.37298e-6 |
| 2.60094 | 0.00384187 |
| 0.00145163 | 2.14421e-6 |

Thus, when taking the log, the corresponding $y_2$-values are $-\infty$, and $\bar y_2 = -\infty$ as well. This makes it impossible to fit the joint normal distribution by the conventional max likelihood method.

**How should I deal with zeros when fitting a log-normal distribution?**

Is trimming the extreme values the best option? Is there another fitting paradigm besides max likelihood that I can use? Or am I chasing a dead end and in need of a new distribution entirely?

Comment: add +1 "smoothing" ? depends what you need the distribution for

Comment: Your numbers may have rounded to $0$.  My guess is that they are in fact saying "less then $2^{-24}\approx 5.96\times 10^{-8}$" or something like that - you might try seeing whether using that as a censorship bound helps at all

Comment: @Henry This "works" in the sense that it produces finite statistics, but it feels a bit like a programmer's solution to the problem rather than a statistician's. I guess I am wondering if there is something like a "trimmed covariance" that I can use, analogous to trimmed estimators of the population varance like those based on the IQR (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimmed_estimator)).

Comment: You might be able to describe your data as a mixture between a lognormal distribution and a point mass at zero. Take a look at "zero inflation" models. These are more common for discrete distributions rather than lognormals, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think your general idea (of transforming into multivariate normal) is good. Keep in mind that the covariance matrix $Cov(y_1,y_2)$ differs from $Cov(x_1, x_2)$ (see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/533804/covariance-of-log-transformed-variable)).

I agree with @henry that your zeros are likely to be a result of rounding. If this is not the case you data includes zeros, it cannot come from the log-normal distribution, just as negative values can't come from the Beta distribution. You can, however, try an alternative distribution, such as the one-sided normal: $X_i\sim{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)\cdot I\{x_i \geq 0\}$. It is present in IRT modeling.