# Lognormal including 0

Tags: probability, distributions, lognormal-distribution, zero-inflation

I'm trying to model a random variable $X_i$ related to updates in prices. The updates in prices are always **non-negative**, and my random variable is the update coefficient. For example, if product $a$ had a price of 100 and and now has a price of 110, then $X_a$ is $0.1$ because $NewPrice_a = OldPrice_a + OldPrice_a \cdot X_a$.

I know that the distribution of price updates is lognormal for the subset of price updates that are different from 0, but what's the distribution when I'm also including those cases where there was no update in prices: $NewPrice_i = OldPrice_i \Rightarrow X_i = 0$.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/535260/fitting-a-joint-log-normal-distribution-when-observations-include-zeros

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your data-generating process essentially has two possible outcomes, one always producing a zero observation and the other producing an observation that is distributed according to some other nondegenerate distribution, this is called *zero inflation*. This is essentially a case of mixtures of distributions, one of the components being a degenerate distribution, i.e., a point mass at zero.

Zero inflation is commonly modeled in the discrete case - there are zero inflated Poisson and zero inflated negative binomial distributions - but [there are people discussing zero inflated lognormal distributions](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=zero+inflated+lognormal+distribution). We have [a few threads tagged both "zero-inflation" and "lognormal-distribution"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lognormal-distribution+zero-inflation). (Now we have one more.)

Comment: Hi Stephan. Thank you so much for your answer. It’s much clearer now. I need to model this phenomenon using R, would you suggest modeling whether the product will have a price update using a logistic distribution, and afterwards modeling lognormal-ly the price coefficient conditional to having a price update? Or this would be incorrect and I need to go for a zero-inflation lognormal distribution?

Comment: Hm. I unfortunately don't have a lot of experience modeling zero inflation. But your approach should be correct. The advantage of a zero-inflated lognormal is that the lognormal component does not contribute any zeros, so we know that any zeros come from that point mass, which is why your method should work. (In contrast, for a zero-inflated Poisson or negative binomial, we would need to disentangle how likely any given zero is to come from the point mass or from the other component, which *does* contribute zeros - so we have to set up a complicated likelihood.) So you should be good to go!

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!